# Notice: Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success'

Tags: php, notice

Anyone able to assist on fixing this one annoying error been trying for like 30minutes.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['statusBtn']))
{
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['address']);
    strtolower($username);
    if(empty($username))
    {
        echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-md-7" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Fill in all fields</div></center>';
    } else if($username == "" || $username == ""){
        echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-md-7" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>Domain Whitelisted</div></center>';
    } else {
        $geo = @file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/{$username}");
        $json_a = json_decode($geo, true);
        $proxyid = $json_a['status'];
        if($proxyid == success)
        {
            echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-success alert-dismissible fade in col-md-7" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>'.htmlspecialchars($username).' is Online!</div></center>';
        } else {
            echo '<center><div class="alert alert-icon alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-md-7" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button><i class="mdi mdi-check-all"></i>'.htmlspecialchars($username).' is Offline!</div></center>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I submit for example google.com in form it echo's the result along with error

> Notice: Use of undefined constant success - assumed 'success'

Comment: How do you read this?

Comment: Note that the `center` tag is obsolete .

Answer (score 4):

change `if($proxyid == success)` to `if($proxyid == 'success')`

The error tells you that `success` without `' '` means that is a constant, instead of a string.